# Не отображается конструктор и не работает отладка при Live Share

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Если пригласить в проект Visual Studio (WPF, .NET) через Live Share, конструктор макета отображается только у меня, запускать отладку тоже можно только на моем устройстве. Как сделать так, чтобы это мог делать каждый участник?

Comment: Для удаленной отладки требуется `Remote debugger`   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2019